# Why is moment.js diff method returning NaN?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, serialization, momentjs

Terminal output:

```
Now:  { _d: Sat Jan 13 2018 02:39:25 GMT-0400 (AST),
      _isUTC: false,
      _a: null,
      _lang: false }
Expiration Date: { _d: Wed Feb 13 2013 02:00:15 GMT-0400 (AST),
      _isUTC: false,
      _a: null,
      _lang: false }
Difference between Now and Expiration Date: NaN
```

Code:

```
console.log('Difference between Now and Expiration Date:', now.diff(expDate, 'months', true));
```

moment.js source:

```
diff : function (input, val, asFloat) {
            var inputMoment = this._isUTC ? moment(input).utc() : moment(input).local(),
                zoneDiff = (this.zone() - inputMoment.zone()) * 6e4,
                diff = this._d - inputMoment._d - zoneDiff,
                year = this.year() - inputMoment.year(),
                month = this.month() - inputMoment.month(),
                date = this.date() - inputMoment.date(),
                output;
            if (val === 'months') {
                output = year * 12 + month + date / 30;
            } else if (val === 'years') {
                output = year + (month + date / 30) / 12;
            } else {
                output = val === 'seconds' ? diff / 1e3 : // 1000
                    val === 'minutes' ? diff / 6e4 : // 1000 * 60
                    val === 'hours' ? diff / 36e5 : // 1000 * 60 * 60
                    val === 'days' ? diff / 864e5 : // 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                    val === 'weeks' ? diff / 6048e5 : // 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
                    diff;
            }
            return asFloat ? output : round(output);
        }
```

Comment: Are you using the latest moment.js? I'm using 1.7.2 and it's giving me back `59`.

Comment: Yes, I am using 1.7.2. I did `moment(expDate._d)` and it worked. Any idea why?

Comment: Is expDate a real moment()-generated object? Or something you deserialized from JSON?

Comment: It is a field from a JSON object as such: `expDate: moment()`. To that field I later perform `expDate.add('M', 1)` and put the whole JSON in mongodb. Then later I pull the `expDate` field from mongodb and perform the diff method on it. Something in that process that could mess the moment() object up?

Comment: Yeah, it will be stored as a plain object in MongoDB, when you retrieve it you have to create a new moment object again (using `moment(expDate._d)`, like you found out) before you can use it for calculations.

Comment: I guess this behavior will repeat itself with any type of custom JSON objects I put into MongoDB, right?

Comment: It depends, if those objects are instances of class-like objects with methods and such it'll give the same issues, MongoDB handles plain objects only so when retrieving those objects they return as plain JS objects.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue when comparing two moment objects. The problem I had was that the first moment was constructed specifying a UK date format while the second moment was created without specifying the UK date format and the date happened to have a day greater than 12 e.g 27th of the month. On closer inspection while debugging, the second date's moment object noted that its _d field was an invalid date.

```
var startDate = moment("23/09/2019", "DD/MM/YYYY");
var endDate = moment("27/09/2019");
var dateDiff = startDate.diff(endDate, "days"); // returns NaN
```

The fix was to construct the second moment object and specify the date format.

```
var endDate = moment("27/09/2019", "DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Answer (score 7):

From comments of the question, I gather that you are attempting to store a `moment` instance directly into MongoDB and then retrieve it later.

A `moment` isn't directly serializable, so this will always cause issues.  You should instead obtain an ISO string from the moment:

```
var m = moment();
var s = m.toISOString(); //  "2013-08-02T20:13:45.123Z"
```

Store that string in MongoDB.  Later, when you retrieve it, you can construct a new moment instance from that value.

```
var m = moment("2013-08-02T20:13:45.123Z");
```

If you prefer something more compact, you could use the number obtained from `m.valueOf()` instead.  But that's not as easy to read or manipulate.

Don't use the `_d` field suggested in comments.  That is internal to moment, and shouldn't be used directly.  It might not be what you are expecting.

Comment: thanks! @matt-johnson that ISO string worked for me. Had an issue using moment() diff() on cordova/phonegap SDK where the timestamp data was coming from JSON/Database.

Comment: @whitedeath - not sure exactly what you mean, but you can indeed use other formats.  You just have to [specify the format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Comment: no worries my comment might help someone else as it helped in my context (mobile hybrid - cordova/phonegap SDK project - where the data timestamp was coming from a JSON/Database response it was returning NaN when converting the moment() - your ISO string fixed this if that was stored instead).